# What is the proper way to run an sql script in my MySql shell utility, for win10?

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I want to create a script written by someone else in order to create tables and entries etc. in my own database.

The command I want to run is:

mysql -h localhost -u root shop < C:/myInstance/web/website/sql/myWeb.sql

I got this line by reading a couple of posts on SO. Yet I got these error message:

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql -h localhost -u root shop < C:/myInstance/web/website/sql/myWeb.sql' at line 1

This suggests that there is clearly a syntax error, at this point I'm not even sure if the error is within my command of that file. Can you help me? I'm quite new to this, here is that file:

```
create table store_product
(
   id bigint auto_increment primary key,
   name varchar(32) not null,
   description varchar(500),
   imageSrc varchar(500),
   price double not null
);


create table store_user
(
    id bigint auto_increment primary key,
    name varchar(32) unique not null,
    password  varchar(16) not null,
    address varchar(100),
    postCode varchar(10),
    email varchar(50),
    homePhone varchar(32),
    cellPhone varchar(32),
    officePhone varchar(32),
    type varchar(20),
    workNo varchar(20)
);
insert into store_user values(1,'throne212','123',' XXX ','621000','throne212@xxx.com','123456789','123456789','123456789','common',null);
insert into store_user values(2,'admin','123','','','admin@xxx.com','','','','admin','001');


create table store_order(
    id bigint  primary key,
    orderNum varchar(17) unique not null,
    status integer not null,
    user_id bigint references store_user(id),
    cost double(10,2)
);

create table store_order_item(
    id bigint auto_increment primary key,
    amount integer not null,
    product_id bigint references store_product(id),
    order_id bigint references store_order(id)
);
```

Comment: What is the command line syntax ?  It looks like you are missing -p. Also, have you considered downloading a GUI like MySQL Workbench, where you can execute scripts and queries.

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply! I thought about it but I deliberately avoided it because I don't want to have my skills horned towards a specific platform, I want it to be OS-neutral, in other words, cmd lines can be applied on both linux consoles and windows consoles whereas point-and-clickies can't. Also -p did not seem to work?